# C# Array List Sort - IComparer

Tags: c#, arrays, list, sorting

I do have an array list which contains several points (x,y). How can i sort this list according to one criteria, maybe x?

```
ArrayList List_Numbers = new ArrayList();
Random ValRandom = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    Point point = new Point(ValRandom.Next(100), ValRandom.Next(100));
    List_Numbers.Add(point);
}
PrintValues(List_Numbers);
List_Numbers.Sort(,);
```

Visual studio proposes as parameter in the sort method the so called `IComparer`. 
How can I use this `IComparer` - there isn't really a description available...

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Microsoft recommends that `ArrayList` is not used for new development. [ArrayList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

There is documentation in iComparer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.icomparer

You need to define a class with a method (`Compare`) that implements your comparison criteria.

Comment: I tried this several times, but it doesn't make sense:


```
    public class SortBy_ArrList_2ndPoint : IComparer
    {

        int IComparer.Compare(Object x, Object y)
        {
            return ((new Comparer(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)).Compare(x, y));
        }
    }
```

I call this function with List_Numbers.Sort(new SortBy_ArrList_2ndPoint());

Comment: You need to implement Compare so that is uses *your* logic for comparing 2 objects (in your case, 2 Points).